# How do I center an image horizontally within a div?

Tags: alignment, center

Here's the code. I can't figure out how to make the image be horizontally centered inside the div. Thanks in advance!

```
.first {
    height: 100%;
}
.first img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.first {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.first img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; // this line is only required if your img is not already using display: inline-block
}
```